# Python If else statement have a bug maybe

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return

```
def evod(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("The number is even")
    return"The number is odd"

print(evod(60))


Output:
The number is even
The number is odd
```

if I run this function it prints both lines. It should print a single one of those. Why is this happening? Please help...

Comment: The code is correct. In case it is an even number, it first enters the if statement, then the next line will be executed which is the return line. Add an `if else` and I would switch to pure print statements and a return value as `True False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing one inside the function and returning the other one every time, you need to return both and let the `print` from outside be the one actually printing it.

```py
def evod(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return "The number is even"
    return "The number is odd"

print(evod(60))
```

Output:

```
The number is even
```

Comment: you might wanna explain why both were being printed

Comment: Cool. Another way would be to put the print in an `if` & `else`. U dont need to print outside then.

Comment: @leoOrion Multiple alternative solutions such as `return "The number is even" if number % 2 == 0 else "The number is odd"`

Answer (score 0):

First mistake is you are printing the line"The number is even".
Replace print with return

Answer (score 0):

If your number is even, you use print() to return an answer. Your code doesnt end there though, as print() doesnt work like return. So both the print and return statement get excecuted.